# C++: Instâncias de uma mesma classe

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Eu tenho em um projeto uma classe `Collision`, e para fazer uma detecção mais eficiente, queria ter acesso a todas as instâncias (objetos) dessa mesma classe. Há alguma forma fácil de fazer isso?

**Edit 1**
Eu fiz assim: criei uma classe chamada `world`, que armazena todos os objetos e colisões, onde tenho o método `isColliding`, que verifica a colisão entre um objeto e todos os outros, ou entre dois objetos.

Comment: Você pode salvar em um array toda instância da classe logo ao criar o novo objeto no construtor e remover do vetor ao desconstruir o objeto. Esteja ciente de quem comparar todos os objetos instanciados talvez não seja a melhor solução, essa alternativa solução que você propôs está correta, mas pode custar muito processamento e deixar o jogo lento

Comment: Pensei em algo desse naipe. Um container `static` (e.g., `vector`, `set`, `map` ou `unordered_set`) com ponteiros para cada instância. Construtores e destrutores respectivamente adicionam ou removem elementos da coleção.

Comment: Postem como resposta.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado , se eu não verificar com todos os objetos, como que vou analisar a colisão?

Comment: @bigown digitar no celular é oneroso. Estou com outra questão em rascunho, terminando aquela eu volto para essa

Comment: @FelipeNascimento segmentação por posição/classes de colisor; tartarugas vermelhas do Mario não precisam saber que tem chão, só se movem entre pontos fixos, então não precisamos colidir elas com o chão. Na futura resposta entrarei com mais detalhes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para não ficar sem registro de resposta, respondo aqui o que já foi respondido nos comentários e feito pelo OP: crie um container com ponteiro para todos os objetos criados, inseridos no momento da construção. Sugiro fazer utilizando uma árvore binária (`std::set`), para reduzir a complexidade:

```
class Collision;

std::set<Collision> world;

class Collision {
public:
    Collision() {
        world.insert(this);
    }

    ~Collision() {
        world.erase(world.find(this));
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira você poderá encontrar todos os `Collision` instanciados no seu programa.